# "regsvr32 /u " fails when there's white space in the full path of the dll?

Tags: regsvr32

When I tried to unregister a dll :

```
regsvr32 /u IPCamFilter1.ax
```

A message box saying *LoadLibrary(IPCamFilter1.ax) fails*, how can I unregister it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this may be a dumb answer, but are you running your command prompt as administrator?  (I'm assuming this is a Windows question, right?)

Comment: Given the fact that regsvr32.exe is Windows binary, I guess your assumption is correct :)

Comment: Yes,I'm on windows.I can unregister other dlls.It seems to be caused by that there's white space in the full path of the dll.But how to fix?

Comment: @ollydbg it doesn't matter if there's whitespace in the full path if you unregister from the folder the file's in, though.